# debugging SQL stored procedure call in java

Tags: java, stored-procedures

Hi I have a Stored procedure call with around 30+ IN parameters. I need the know the values of the parameters which are in the call to the SP since I am getting incorrect results.

the call is something like this:

```
return "{call FORECASTS_PKG.GENERATE_FORECAST_TASK(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";
```

I have currently set the breakpoint on the above statement. I see the individual parameters having the values, but wondering if the values are set properly since its wrong results. I am sure the order of the parameters matters here and the values must be set accordingly so that its in the same order as in the Database.
How do I see the values inside this call? I do the the XML reperesentation of the in the implemented toString() method but thats just printed in a different default order.

Once I see the values I can compare to the defeinition in the Database and see if the values are set in the correct order as expected.

Comment: Dumb question.  Why the aren't you using CallableStatement?  You are already have the prerequisites.  This will let you name parameters and add significant ease to your life?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html

Comment: what dbms some allow you to name the arguments. Me I'd have a rethink have a name = value parameter list class or some such. Maintainability wise this is a disaster area.

Comment: Guys I cannot change the existing implementation, I know there could be some improvements, buit these are supposed to be 'quick bug fixes'..

Comment: Change connection.prepareStatement(...) to connection.prepareCall("FORECASTS_PKG.GENERATE_FORCAST_TASK").  (I realize you cannot do that and I have similar issues in code I maintain but it at least would be 1000% easier to debug)

Comment: Oh as for your actual question.  If it's a proper database (eg. SQL Server) have the DBAs put a break point in the Stored procedure and then check the from Management studio.  Quick fix from there.